# How can i filter out information in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, remote-access, remote-desktop

How can I filter out information in powershell?

For instance, i run system info on a remote machine,
I would write:

```
systeminfo -s <computerName>
```

However how can i do this for many machines and also how can I filter out the information?

I want to search many machines for just "Total Physical Memory"

[image: Screenshot of system info]

Comment: instead of using that  ... icky util, why don't you use the powershell CIM cmdlets to get the info? [*grin*] ///// i'm confused ... do you want the RAM only ... or do you want everything EXCEPT the RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.

How to find "Total Physical Memory" using PowerShell for one computer.  Replace `computername`.

```
systeminfo -s computername | Select-String 'Total Physical Memory:').ToString().Split(':')[1].Trim()
```

I can't test this:

How to find "Total Physical Memory" using a PowerShell function for many computers.

```
Get-SystemInfo -ComputerName server01,server02
```

You can get `get-systeminfo` at [gallery.technet.microsoft.com](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-SystemInfo-Get-a-028c9757).

Comment: What is `Get-SytemInfo`[sic]? Is it [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-SystemInfo-Get-a-028c9757)? Please at a reference. Or did you mean `Get-ComputerInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Lee_Daily, it would be easier and more direct to use Powershell.

This will produce the amount of physical memory in GiB.

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Sum Capacity).Sum / 1GB
```